# Trouble passing object to delete method RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, crud

I am creating a Pinterest clone with Ruby on Rails. Currently I am working on setting up CRUD methods and routes. Create, Read, Update are all working. I am having trouble with DELETE/DESTROY. The error is InvalidAuthenticity, but by turning off the `protect_from_forgery` I can see that the value of `pin` is empty, which is why authenticity fails. Here is my code. Not sure why I am not able to pass the pin value.

Current code state : https://github.com/dustin-longenecker/rails-pinning-app

show.html.erb
I realize there are two buttons because I have been trying both.

```
<form action="<%= "/pins/#{@pin.id}" %>" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete" />
      <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">
        Delete
      </button>
    </form>
<%= link_to "Delete", pin_path(@pin), :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method => :delete %>
```

pins_controller.rb

```
 def destroy
    #@pin.delete(pin_params)
    pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
    pin.destroy(pin_params)
    redirect_to root_path, :notice => "Your patient has been deleted"
  end
  def pin_params
    params.require(:pin).permit(:title, :url, :slug, :text, :category_id)
  end
```

routes.rb

```
delete "/pins/:id" => "pins#destroy"
```

trace

```
app/controllers/pins_controller.rb:55:in `pin_params'
app/controllers/pins_controller.rb:48:in `destroy'
```

So again, it would seem that the `destroy` method is being called appropriately but the `pin` instance is not being passed. The route `/pins/#{id}` is being landed on.

What do I have wrong?

Comment: Can you post the strong parameters method in pins controller?

Comment: Strong parameters method has been updated in pins_controller.rb. Also, tried this out too with the same results ```pin = Pin.find(pin_params)
    pin.destroy```

Comment: Right now, I believe that the problem lies within the `show.html.erb` form that is not passing the `pin` value to the destroy method.

Comment: Also, looking at a rails debugger it shows  that the params are ```_method delete
controller pins
action destroy
id 24``` leading me to believe that the params exist.

Comment: Are you sure that the `@pin` instance variable is sent properly from the `show` action in the controller?